# Issues with workers dying and garbage collection summing over rows of Dataframe with distributed DASK

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I am new to dask, so this is likely a case of user error, but I'm a bit perplexed. My problem is essentially that I have a large dataframe (tens of thousands of rows and hundreds to thousands of columns) and I am trying to sum across rows over particular columns. Essentially, each column is an 8 digit hierarchical code, and I would like to create new columns corresponding to the sums of the columns over 6-digit, 4-digit, and 2 digit prefixes. E.g.,

```
for code_part in dig_6: 
   
ddf[code_part] = ddf[[col for col in ddf.columns if col.startswith(code_part)]].sum(axis=1)
```

I'm testing this on a subset of the data, with a dask dataframe with 20 partitions and running with 4 processors. When I attempt to actually compute the code above,

`df = ddf.compute()`,

I get a very large number of garbage collector warnings (e.g.,

```
distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 10% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%) 
distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 11% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%) 
distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 12% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%) 
distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 13% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%) 
distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 14% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%) 
distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 16% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%)
```

),

and also workers dying and being restarted.

Are the garbage collector warnings simply a result of mapping the compute operation to a new dataframe? is it better to overwrite ddf with ddf.compute? And is this kind of sum a challenging operation for dask?

Thanks for the help!